# Fixing libraries view to group by source folder again

Tags: windows-8.1

I did this before and fixed it but can't remember how.

I was in some folder with a lot of photos so I decided to group it by date. Which was great.

Problem is, now ALL my libraries are also grouped by date.. and I can't figure out how to group them by source folder again.

Right now my libraries are a mess, each library looks just like one big folder.

If my library is made of C:\A, C:\B, C:\C

then I want it displayed as:

C:\A
[files]

C:\B
[files]

C:\C
[files]

right now it is is just

[all files]

How can I restore this separated view? thanks

Comment: I can only figure out how to group it by source folder alphabetically but not by the original order of the folders of the libraries... which is what it was doing initially before I lost the grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out... apparently the answer is easy but nobody knows about (after not getting any answers here I asked on Windows forums and believe it or not nobody knew anything there either)

**Answer is:**

> right click / arrange by / clear changes